# How to know at which price an item has been sold in auction house?

Tags: diablo-iii

I am exploring a bit the auction house in order to understand how the prices are going, but I can see only the price of items still available in auction. Does exist a way to see the price of items marked as already `Sold`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt there is a way to see the already sold items,

But you can ensure selling without knowing what the items have been sold for.

The best way to figure out a price is if there already are some. If it's something there already are prices on, trying going a bit under that.

Eg. you want tot sell a Stone of Jordan.

There are already 5 for sale, for around 5000g (this is a fictional price).

Set yours to sell for 4999g.

This is easier if there are a lot of the same item for sale (which can be hard for items with random properties).

Also having a buyout price can help a sale, if the others don't have a buyout price.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to get an approximate idea of the buyout prices of already sold items, but it is a bit tedious.

1) Look at the item which you are interested in. Set search criteria which would match the item you are interested in.

E.g. If you have a +191 strength, +44 resist all, +101 vitality, +50 dexterity ring
Then set the search criteria to 191 minimum strength, 44 minimum all resistances, and 101 minimum vitality.
The purpose of this is to reduce the amount of items that are listed.

2) Ensure that you see the item you are investigating in the search listing. Enter a maximum buyout criteria.

E.g. we can enter 10,000,000 gold. If the item you are investigating is still showing up, the buyout price was lower. If we lower the max buyout criteria to 1,000,000 gold, and the investigated item disappears, we know that the buyout price was larger than one million. If we want a more a precise value, we can increase the buyout criteria until the item shows up again.

Notice though, that this only gives information about the buyout price of the item in question. As far as I know, this technique would result in the conclusion that an item was worth 10,000,000 gold even if the item was sold for only 1,500,000 gold through bids (but had a buyout price of 10,000,000)